# What's wrong with the leaves of lily plants?

Tags: flowers, pest-control, containers, pest-damage

What's wrong with the leaves of lily plants? They seem faded when compared to the other leaves.

Someone told me that they're just older leaves, but I wanted to make sure.

[image]

Comment: check closely beneath the leaves for anything that shouldn't be there, including fine webbing. You will probably need a magnifying glass, some pests are tiny

Answer (score 1):

Pests and/or over-watering, unless you've recently repotted in which case it's probably just die-back.

Inspect for pests. Spider mites have been crazy the last couple of years.

And, forgive me if you already know, but only water when the leaves start to droop noticeably. PLs will tell you when to water, and if you stick to their direction they'll do fantastic. I've also noticed that mine have a special distaste for tap water (chlorine/chloramine messing with the odd dry-moist bacterial blooms, I expect). But really, PLs get watered like a cactus, but with the bonus that they let you know when it's time.

Back to the question: I suspect spider mites. Apply pesticide - I use a tablespoon of Dawn in a half gallon of water sprayed on with a rinse a few minutes later (soil covered/out of the way). Anything commercial will work too, and probably better, if you don't want to mess with homemade.